# iOS: getting weekOfMonth from date issue

Tags: ios, xcode, calendar, nsdate, ios9.2

there is a little issue about getting `WeekOfMonth` from date. This is a sample code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformate setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; // Date formater

NSDate *dateTest1 = [dateformate dateFromString:@"25/07/2016"]; //Week no: 5
NSDate *dateTest2 = [dateformate dateFromString:@"01/08/2016"]; //Week no: 1
NSDate *dateTest3 = [dateformate dateFromString:@"08/08/2016"]; //Week no: 2
NSDate *dateTest4 = [dateformate dateFromString:@"15/08/2016"]; //Week no: 3
NSDate *dateTest5 = [dateformate dateFromString:@"22/08/2016"]; //Week no: 4
NSDate *dateTest6 = [dateformate dateFromString:@"29/08/2016"]; //Week no: 5
NSDate *dateTest7 = [dateformate dateFromString:@"05/09/2016"]; //Week no: 6

components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:dateTest1];
dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateTest1];
NSLog(@"dateTest1 -> %@",dateString); //output : dateTest1 -> 25/07/2016
NSLog(@"Week no: %ld",(long)[components weekOfMonth]); //output : Week no: 4

components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:dateTest2];
dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateTest2];
NSLog(@"dateTest2 -> %@",dateString); //output : dateTest2 -> 01/08/2016
NSLog(@"Week no: %ld",(long)[components weekOfMonth]); //output : Week no: 1

components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:dateTest3];
dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateTest3];
NSLog(@"dateTest3 -> %@",dateString); //output : dateTest3 -> 08/08/2016
NSLog(@"Week no: %ld",(long)[components weekOfMonth]); //output : Week no: 2

components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:dateTest4];
dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateTest4];
NSLog(@"dateTest4 -> %@",dateString); //output : dateTest4 -> 15/08/2016
NSLog(@"Week no: %ld",(long)[components weekOfMonth]); //output : Week no: 3

components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:dateTest5];
dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateTest5];
NSLog(@"dateTest5 -> %@",dateString); //output : dateTest5 -> 22/08/2016
NSLog(@"Week no: %ld",(long)[components weekOfMonth]); //output : Week no: 4

components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:dateTest6];
dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateTest6];
NSLog(@"dateTest6 -> %@",dateString); //output : dateTest6 -> 29/08/2016
NSLog(@"Week no: %ld",(long)[components weekOfMonth]); //output : Week no: 5

components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:dateTest7];
dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateTest7];
NSLog(@"dateTest7 -> %@",dateString); //output : dateTest7 -> 05/09/2016
NSLog(@"Week no: %ld",(long)[components weekOfMonth]); //output : Week no: 2
```

As you can see `dateTest1` should be `Week no = 5` and NOT `Week no = 4`. For the other dates there is no problems as I see and as you can see.

I need the correct `WeekOfMonth` to set my `FFCalendar` properly
https://github.com/fggeraissate/FFCalendar

Answer (score 2):

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let dateComponent = calendar.components([.WeekOfYear, .Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0))
print("weekOfYear \(dateComponent.weekOfYear)")
```

Using above code you can get the weekOfYear. Now you need to calculate weekOfYear of the first date of that month and the date you need to find.
now for getting the weekOfMonth get the diff + 1 of both WeekOfYear

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using weekOfMonth not depends on me, it depends from FFCalendar. On FFWeekCalendarView on method dateChanged, is where i need to set the WeekOfMonth properly, because it works with WeekOfMonth. I don't think I can use weekOfYear instead of weekOfMonth in FFCalendar.

Comment: Sorry now I understand! It works very well. Thank you

Comment: Week of month return 1-4 or 5th and week of year should return 1-52 or 53

Answer (score 0):

Following the solution proposed raj-aggrawal I made this solution that is working good

```
NSDate *date = [[FFDateManager sharedManager] currentDate];

NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformate setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; // Date formater

NSString *dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:date];
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* dateComponent = [calendar components:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger weekOfYearCurrent =(long)[dateComponent weekOfYear];
dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"dateCurrent -> %@",dateString);
NSLog(@"weekOfYearCurrent: %ld",(long)weekOfYearCurrent);

NSDate *dateFirstMonth = [dateformate dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"01/%d/2016", (int)[dateComponent month]]];
dateComponent = [calendar components:NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:dateFirstMonth];
NSInteger weekOfYearFirstDayOfMonth =(long)[dateComponent weekOfYear];
dateString = [dateformate stringFromDate:dateFirstMonth];
NSLog(@"dateFirstMonth -> %@",dateString);
NSLog(@"weekOfYearFirstDayOfMonth: %ld",(long)weekOfYearFirstDayOfMonth);

NSInteger NumberWeekOfMonth = (weekOfYearCurrent - weekOfYearFirstDayOfMonth) + 1;
NSLog(@"NumberWeekOfMonth: %ld",(long)NumberWeekOfMonth);
```